# Função recursiva para calcular a quantidade de letras minúsculas em uma cadeia de caracteres

Tags: java, string, lógica, recursão

Eu consegui fazer uma função para retornar um determinado carácter em uma posição X de uma string:

```
  public static char funcao (String texto, int indice){

    if (indice == 0){

      return texto.charAt(indice);

    } else {

      funcao(texto, indice - 1);

      return texto.charAt(indice);

    } // fim do if

  } // fim da funcao
```

Depois fiz outra função para verificar se a letra nessa posição é minúscula:

```
public static int funcao2 (char letra){

    if ((letra >= 'a') && (letra <= 'z')){

      return 1;

    } else {

      return 0;

    }

  } // fim da funcao2
```

No fim meu teste no `main` ficou assim:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String texto = "aBcdEFGHiJ@1-";

    // quantidade de letras minusculas na String
    int quantLetras = 0;

    for (int indice = 0 ;
         indice <= texto.length() - 1 ;
         indice = indice + 1 ) {

      quantLetras = quantLetras + funcao2(funcao(texto, indice));

      //IO.println ("\nLetra: " + funcao(texto, indice));

    } // fim do for

    IO.println ("\nQuandidade de minusculas: " + quantLetras);

  } // fim do metodo principal
```

No fim o programa funcionou, porém me incomoda a maneira como eu fiz funcionar, etc... Teria um jeito de fazer esse cálculo de letras minúsculas de uma melhor maneira com recursividade?

Comment: nao é duplicata? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/331602/28595

Comment: Tem que ser recursiva? Porque não me parece ser um problema dessa natureza.

Comment: @GustavoFragoso No exercício pede para usar recursão mas não especifica pra que. Estou aprendendo sobre recursão ainda.

Comment: @Articuno Ao meu ver não se trata de duplicata pois estou tratando outro tipos diferentes de resultados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*<sup>O jeito mais fácil é percorrer os caracteres da `String` com um `for` simples, mas se quer mesmo fazer recursivo, vamos lá...</sup>*

---

Antes de mais nada, esta função não é exatamente recursiva:

```
public static char funcao (String texto, int indice){    
    if (indice == 0){    
        return texto.charAt(indice);    
    } else {    
        funcao(texto, indice - 1);    
        return texto.charAt(indice);    
    }
}
```

Quer dizer, você até chama a função dentro dela mesma, mas não usa o resultado desta chamada para nada.

A linha `funcao(texto, indice - 1);` chama a função, mas o retorno dela não é atribuído para nenhuma variável, o que torna esta chamada inútil. E no fim você chama `texto.charAt(indice)`, que é exatamente o mesmo que é feito dentro do `if (indice == 0)`. Ou seja, esta função sempre retorna `texto.charAt(indice)`.

Não tem porque pegar o caractere da posição X de forma recursiva, pois o método `charAt` já retorna este caractere diretamente. Podemos então descartar esta função.

---

Para verificar de maneira recursiva se os caracteres de uma `String` são letras minúsculas, podemos considerar o seguinte:

- se a `String` é vazia, o resultado é zero
- se a `String` não é vazia, o resultado é a soma de duas coisas:

  - `1` ou `0` (dependendo do primeiro caractere ser minúsculo ou não)
  - o total de caracteres minúsculos do restante da `String` (do segundo caractere em diante)

Um exemplo: se a `String` for `Abc` e aplicarmos o algoritmo acima, como ficaria?

- a `String` é vazia? Não, então vamos para o próximo passo
- o primeiro caractere (`A`) é minúsculo? Não, então o resultado parcial é **zero**.
- agora eu verifico o restante da `String` (`bc`)

  - o primeiro caractere (`b`) é minúsculo? Sim, então o resultado parcial **deste passo** (ou seja, do pedaço `bc`) é 1
  - agora eu verifico o restante da `String` (`c`)

    - o primeiro caractere (`c`) é minúsculo? Sim, então o resultado parcial **deste passo** (ou seja, do pedaço `c`) é 1
    - agora eu verifico o restante da `String` (a `String` vazia, porque acabaram os caracteres)
    - como a `String` é vazia, o resultado parcial deste passo é zero.

Somando os resultados parciais de cada passo, o resultado é 2.

---

O código ficaria assim:

```
public static int contaLetrasMinusculas(String texto) {
    // se a String for vazia, retorna zero
    if (texto.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    // verifica se o primeiro caractere da String é minúsculo
    char primeiro = texto.charAt(0);
    // se for minúsculo, "c" é igual a 1, senão é zero
    int c = Character.isLowerCase(primeiro) ? 1 : 0;

    // retorna "c" + a contagem do restante da string
    return c + contaLetrasMinusculas(texto.substring(1));
}
```

Alguns exemplos de uso:

```
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("")); // 0
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("A")); // 0
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("b")); // 1
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("aBcdEFGHiJ@1-")); // 4
```

Claro que dá para deixar mais sucinto, mas aí você vê se assim fica menos legível/mais difícil de entender:

```
public static int contaLetrasMinusculas(String texto) {
    if (texto.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (Character.isLowerCase(texto.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0)
           + contaLetrasMinusculas(texto.substring(1));
}
```

---

### Unicode

O código acima funciona bem para o nosso alfabeto. Mas para funcionar com quaisquer caracteres Unicode, devemos fazer algumas modificações. Para mais detalhes sobre como o Unicode funciona, recomendo o [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html) e [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).

Em linhas gerais, o Unicode permite que sejam usados caracteres que não cabem em um `char` (e são armazenados internamente em dois `chars` - o chamado *surrogate pair*). Por isso usar esta abordagem de `charAt` não funciona para estes caracteres.

E em vez usar `char`, usamos codepoints (que é o código numérico que todos os caracteres possuem dentro do Unicode).

Se quiser uma solução mais geral que funcione com quaisquer caracteres Unicode, o código fica assim:

```
static int contaLetrasMinusculas(String texto) {
    if (texto.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    // primeiro Unicode codepoint da String
    int primeiro = texto.codePointAt(0);
    int c = Character.isLowerCase(primeiro) ? 1 : 0;
    // Character.charCount verifica se o codepoint ocupa um ou dois chars
    return c + contaLetrasMinusculas(texto.substring(Character.charCount(primeiro)));
}
```

O código continua funcionando para os casos anteriores:

```
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("")); // 0
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("A")); // 0
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("b")); // 1
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("aBcdEFGHiJ@1-")); // 4
```

Mas agora funciona também para outros caracteres Unicode, como por exemplo o  [(DESERET SMALL LETTER LONG I)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10428/index.htm), que corresponde ao Unicode codepoint 66600 e é considerado minúscula:

```
// DESERET SMALL LETTER LONG I http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10428/index.htm
String s = new String(Character.toChars(66600));
System.out.println(contaLetrasMinusculas("aA" + s + "Bb")); // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está bastante confuso para uma solução recursiva. Para resolver o problema fizemos o seguinte:

- Adotamos como condição de parada um texto de tamanho 1;

  - Se o character estiver uppercase retorna 1, senão retorno 0;
- Para cada chamada vamos dividir o texto em 2 metades, até alcançarmos a condição de parada especificada. (Semelhante ao que acontece na primeira etapa do mergesort)

O código é o seguinte:

```
public int minusculas(String texto) {
    int length = texto.length();
    if(length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(length == 1) {
        return Character.isLowerCase(texto.charAt(0)) ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        return minusculas(texto.substring(0, length/2)) + minusculas(texto.substring(length/2, length));
    }
}
```

Aqui temos o stacktrace da execução do algoritmo:

```
Texto: aBcdEFGHiJ@1-    esq: aBcdEF dir: GHiJ@1-    
Texto: aBcdEF           esq: aBc    dir: dEF
Texto: aBc              esq: a      dir: Bc
Texto: Bc               esq: B      dir: c
Texto: dEF              esq: d      dir: EF
Texto: EF               esq: E      dir: F
Texto: GHiJ@1-          esq: GHi    dir: J@1- // Começa a avaliar o lado direito
Texto: GHi              esq: G      dir: Hi
Texto: Hi               esq: H      dir: i
Texto: J@1-             esq: J@     dir: 1-
Texto: J@               esq: J      dir: @
Texto: 1-               esq: 1      dir: -
```

O resultado será 4.